# Analyzing the Impact: Customized Bloodline for Artificer Build

Tags: dnd-3.5e, homebrew-review, artificer, bloodline

I'm planning to create an artificer for a new campaign starting from level 1, and I'm considering incorporating a customized bloodline into my character concept. However, I'd like to gather some insights and analysis on the potential impact this decision might have on my character's progression.

The customized Intermediate Bloodline (2 levels) I'm considering contains the following feats: Disciple of Boccoc*, Maximize Spell, Quicken Spell, Improved Initiative, and Spell Penetration.

> **Disciple of Boccoc:** This feat allows me to qualify for item creation feats as if I were one level higher. Additionally, any magic items I create are crafted at +1 caster level, without incurring the extra cost associated with a higher caster level. However, if I destroy a permanent magic item, I lose all arcane spellcasting abilities for a day per caster level of the item.

My main concern is understanding the impact of delaying spellcasting progression and assessing the benefits of having these feats compared to the losses incurred, such as decreased hit dice, skill points, craft reserve, and the bonus feat at level 20 that artificers typically receive.

Please keep in mind that the bloodline is equivalent to a class, so it's not possible to "buy back" the invested levels with experience points.

Any clarity and insights you can provide on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What level do you expect the campaign to actually get to?

Comment: I hope it is a long campaign and we reach level 20…

Comment: Considering that our various Q&As on the subject of bloodlines are full of “the rules are unclear” and “no one knows for sure how they work,” I think this question needs more details about how they are going to work at _your table_, rather than assuming that they work consistently—they don’t. For instance, our canonical Q&A on the subject has at least one upvoted claim that “the bloodline is equivalent to a class, so it's not possible to ‘buy back’ the invested levels with experience points,” is incorrect.

Comment: I believe that you misspelled Disciple of Boccob, and also called it a feat when it is an alternative class feature.

Comment: Well, indeed, the feats and the alternative class feature (Equivalent to a feat because it replace a feat) are all included in the "Special" category of the Bloodlines. That is not the point.